# Transcribe + Wygwam + Structure links not working

Tags: ee2, wygwam, structure, transcribe

When adding Structure Links to a wygwam field on a Transcribe entry that's not the default language, they are being rendered like this: `<a href="{page_168}">`

More info:

I have a Transcribe site with Structure and Wygwam. Each language has it's own domain (example.com, `example.de` etc) When I add a Structure Link into Wygwam for the default language (eg `example.com`) by clicking Link Icon > Link Style: Structure > then selecting a page, it puts the link in and works fine (eg `http://example.com/news/the_story`). However if I add an entry for the non-default language (eg `example.de`) and then add a Structure Link into Wygwam the URL appears fine in wygwam but when it appears on the site it shows `<a href="{page_168}">` .

After investigation it looks like the page id is referencing the entry id for the default language and not the current language the entry is for. The list of pages that are shown in the Structure Link dropdown is only ever for the default language and not the current language.

I think what's happening is wygwam is looking for the URL based on the default language and then converting that the `{page_XX}` variable but it's getting it wrong because it's ignoring the domain name and choosing the page id that's on the default language. Is there any way to fix this?

EE v2.11.2, Transcribe v1.7.1, Structure v3.3.19, Wygwam v3.3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spoke to the developer, this is a known bug. They will fix it at some point.

Comment: Does that ever been fixed?

Comment: They emailed me to say it has been fixed. I haven't tried it though.